# verificar "vecinos" en un array Bidimensional - Python

Tags: python, array-bidimensional

Tengo un array Bidimensional (5x5) el cual principalmente contiene *ceros (0)*, de tal forma

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

luego esta se va llenado con *unos (1)* en posiciones aleatorias, para posteriormente asignarle un puntaje, este puntaje depende de los vecinos que tenga *1* y si tiene los cuatro vecinos se le suma un punto

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

en este caso el puntaje de mi arreglo seria *1 punto* ya que el 1 se encuentra rodeado de 4 *ceros*, he intentado esto de dos formas, pero no se si existe una forma de simplificar este proceso

**Primera forma**

```
def puntage(lista):
    lenL = len(lista)
    puntos = 0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        for e in range(len(lista[i])):
            element = lista[i][e-1]
            beforeE = lista[i][e-2]
            neighborUp = lista[i-1][e]
            if i !=lenL -1 listai !=0:
                neigborDown = lista[i+1][e]
                if neigborDown == 0 and neighborUp == 0 and element == 0 and beforeE==0:
                    puntos +=1
            if i == lenL -1:
                if neighborUp == 0 and element == 0 and beforeE==0:
                     puntos +=1
            if i == 0:
                neigborDown = lista[i+1][e]
                if neigborDown == 0 and element == 0 and beforeE==0: puntos +=1
    return puntos
```

la segunda forma que intente fue separando cada parte del arreglo 2D, separandolo por *'filas'* y obtener su puntaje de esa forma sin embargo solo obtengo el puntaje referente a sus veciones laterales esto ya que solo se reibe una *'fila'*

**Segunda forma (2 funciones)**

```
def checkRowsNeighbors(row):
    fit = 0
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if i == 0: continue
        if i == 1:
            if row[i-1] == 0: fit+=1
            continue
        NLeft1 = row[i-1]
        NLeft2 = row[i-2]
        if NLeft1 == 0 and NLeft2 == 0: fit+=1
    return fit
         
def NewPuntaje(lista):
    fit = 0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if i == 0:
            nextNeighbor = lista[i+1]
            check = checkRowsNeighbors(nextNeighbor)
            fit+= check
            continue
        if i == (len(lista)-1):
            beforeNeighbor = lista[i-1]
            check=checkRowsNeighbors(beforeNeighbor)
            fit+= check
            continue
        nextNeighbor = lista[i+1]
        c1=checkRowsNeighbors(nextNeighbor)
        fit+=c1
        beforeNeighbor = lista[i-1]
        c2=checkRowsNeighbors(beforeNeighbor)
        fit+=c2
    return fit
```

mi pregunta es, hay alguna forma mas simplificada (o diferente) de obtener los vecinos en un arreglo?, si no existe, como podria mejorar mi codigo?

Comment: Una posición, ¿Siempre puede tener 4 posibles vecinos? ¿Qué pasa con los extremos?

Comment: Esos arrays ¿son `numpy`? porque en ese caso puede cambiar la sintaxis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Errores en tu código

Lo primero, el código que has puesto en la "primera forma" es incorrecto. Tiene algún error de sintaxis, como en la línea:

```
            if i !=lenL -1 listai !=0:
```

en la que la condición no es una expresión booleana válida, y además usa el símbolo no definido `listai`. Entiendo que debería ser:

```
            if i !=lenL -1 and lista[i][e] !=0:
```

También contiene errores de lógica en los siguientes `if`, ya que en ellos deberías mirar también si el elemento es distinto de cero y no lo haces. Es decir, por ejemplo, éste:

```
            if i == lenL -1:
```

debería ser

```
            if i == lenL -1 and lista[i][e] != 0:
```

Con esas correcciones tu código ya produce como resultado 1, que es lo que entiendo debería ser el resultado correcto.

### Otra versión

Creo que el código se puede simplificar mucho y hacerse más legible con un par de "trucos":

1. En cada iteración del bucle, lo primero, mira si `lista[i][e]` es cero. En ese caso ejecutas `continue`, que se saltará ese elemento y pasará a la siguiente iteración. Así, el resto de instrucciones ya no tienen que andar mirando si el elemento es distinto de cero.
2. Podemos escribir una función auxiliar `get_vecinos()` que nos devuelva una lista con los 2, 3 ó 4 vecinos que tenga una coordenada dada. Para saber si todos los vecinos son cero bastará entonces hacer `sum()` de la lista de vecinos.

Con estas ayudas la función quedará así de sencilla:

```
def puntaje(lista):
  puntos = 0
  for i in range(len(lista)):
    for e in range(len(lista[i])):
      if lista[i][e] == 0:       # Si es cero, nos lo saltamos
        continue

      # En caso contrario vemos si la suma de sus vecinos es cero
      vecinos = get_vecinos(lista, i, e)
      if sum(vecinos) == 0:
        puntos+=1
  return puntos
```

Solo queda escribir la función que retorna la lista de vecinos. Ésta también se puede simplificar mucho con la estructura de control apropiada:

```
def get_vecinos(lista, i, j):
  vecinos = []
  for d_i, d_j in ((-1, 0), (+1, 0), (0, -1), (0, +1)):
    # Añadirlo a la lista de vecinos si está dentro de los límites del array
    if 0 <= i+d_i < len(lista) and 0 <= j+d_j < len(lista[i]):
      vecinos.append(lista[i+d_i][j+d_j])
  return vecinos
```

Test:

```
lista = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

print(puntaje(lista))
```

Salida: `1`

Comment: una pregunta, que es lo que hace ```((-1, 0), (+1, 0), (0, -1), (0, +1)):```, podrias dejarme la documentacion o una pagina donde halla ejemlos para saber mas de esa forma del ciclo ```for```

Comment: En realidad es un `for` normal. La misión de un `for` es ir recorriendo los elementos de un iterable. En este caso el iterable es la secuencia de tuplas que mencionas. Así, en la primera iteración se obtiene la tupla `(-1,0)`, en la siguiente la `(+1,0)`, etc. Esas tuplas se asignan a la pareja de variables `d_i, d_j`. Por tanto en la primera iteración `d_i` valdrá -1 y `d_j` valdrá 0. En la siguiente `d_i` será +1 y `d_j` será 0, etc. De esa forma voy obteniendo los "offsets" que quiero sumar a `i` y `j` para ir llegando a cada uno de sus cuatro vecinos (que corresponden a las cuatro tuplas)

Comment: lo del ```for``` si lo se, solo queria saber cual era el significado de esa sintaxis, gracias por explicarmelo