# Entrar en todos los bucles no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un ejercicio de clase de python y me pide recorrer un array bidimensional y buscar occurencias (Un tic tac toe), me pide comprobar en filas, columnas y en "barrido".

Entonces, por separado los bucles me buscan bien, pero si los junto en un mismo "programa" me salta al último y pasa del resto.

Quiero que entre en el primero, compruebe que no hay ocurrencias en la misma fila, luego pase al de columnas, desde la izquierda a la derecha y si sigue sin encontrar pase al contrario (de derecha a izquierda).

Este es mi código, os agradecería me echaseis una mano. Un saludo y cualquier otro apunte que necesitáis que escriba os lo pongo.

```
arr = [['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'O', 'X']]

for fila in arr:
    m_f_x = 0
    m_f_y = 0
    for columna in fila:
        if(columna == 'X'):
            m_f_x = m_f_x + 1
        if(columna == 'O'):
            m_f_y = m_f_y + 1
    if(m_f_x == 3 or m_f_y == 3):
        break;

for i in range(len(arr[0])):
    m_f_x = 0
    m_f_y = 0
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        if(arr[x - (i % 2) * (x + x + 1)][i] == 'X'):
            m_f_x = m_f_x + 1
        if(arr[x - (i % 2) * (x + x + 1)][i] == 'O'):
            m_f_y = m_f_y + 1
    if(m_f_x == 3 or m_f_y == 3):
        break;

i = 0
m_f_x = 0
m_f_y = 0
for x in range(0, len(arr[0])):
    if(arr[x][i] == 'X'):
        m_f_x = m_f_x + 1
    if(arr[x][i] == 'O'):
        m_f_y = m_f_y + 1
    if(m_f_x == 3 or m_f_y == 3):
        break;
    i = i + 1
    
m_f_x = 0
m_f_y = 0
for x in range(0, len(arr[0])):
    print(arr[x])
    if(arr[x][i] == 'X'):
        m_f_x = m_f_x + 1
    if(arr[x][i] == 'O'):
        m_f_y = m_f_y + 1
    if(m_f_x == 3 or m_f_y == 3):
        break;
    i = i - 1

for i in range(len(arr[0])):
        for x in range(len(arr)):
            print(arr[x - (i % 2) * (x + x + 1)][i])
        print()

print('CPU' if m_f_x == 3 else 'Usuario' if m_f_y == 3 else 'Empate')
```

Quisiera que si el array fuera como en el que puse al principio solo me salte al primero y no haga más, si fuese la 'O' en arr[0][0], arr[1][0] y arr[2][0] (o en cualquier columna) me pase al segundo, si fuese arr[0][0], arr[1][1] y arr[2][2] me salte el tercero y el cuarto sería al revés...

Y al final hago comprobación de quién "GANA", X es CPU y O es Usuario.

Comment: Tal ves esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/440632/183782) te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en primer lugar tu código se puede simplificar mucho y se puede hacer mas legible, y mas optimizado, primero vamos usar la función `count()` para contar cada fila de la lista `arr[i]`, `count()` acepta un parámetro para que sepa que valor contar, en este caso será `x` y `0`, luego vamos a crear una función encargada de contar las columnas, y finalmente otra para contar las dígnales.

**Nota:** cambie el nombre de las variables

```py
#funcion para contar columnas
#jugadas = {} esto sera definido dentro de la funcion final

def get_columns(lista):
    for j in range(len(lista)):
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            jugada = lista[i][j] #esto contendra "X" o "O"

            #vamos a almacenar en un diccionario cada vez que se encuentre esto
            if (j,jugada) in jugadas: 
                #guardamos la clave como tupla (columna, valor)
                jugadas[(j,jugada)] += 1
                if jugadas[(j,jugada)] == 3: #comprobamos si es 3
                  return jugada #retornamos el valor, el ciclo ya no continua

            #en caso sea la primera vez que aparezca le asignamos el valor de 1
            else:
                jugadas[(j,jugada)] = 1 

    return #si no enceuntra nada retorna un valor falsy
```

**Funcion final**

```
def get_winner(lista):
    jugadas = {} #este es el diccionario

    for j in lista: #j es cada fila
        if j.count("X") == 3: #primmero contamos en horizontal(fila por fila)
            return "X" #si es 3 retornamos el valor de "X"
        elif j.count("O") == 3:#lo mismo pero con el otro valor "O"
            return "=" #igual retornamos

    #si la suma en horizontal no devuelve un ganador, sumamos en vertical
    columns = get_columns(lista)

    #si la suma vertical no devuelve un valor, sumamos en diagonal
    if not columns:
        #se le pasa las coordenadas que iterara
        #o representa la columna y x la fila -> recomendado cambiar a "c" y "f"
        for o, x in ((0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(0,2),(2,0)):
            #si ya estaba le sumamos 1
            if lista[o][x] in jugadas:
                jugadas[lista[o][x]] += 1
                #comprobamos 
                if jugadas[lista[o][x]] == 3:
                  return lista[o][x]

            #si aparece por primera vez le asignamos el valor 1
            else:
              jugadas[lista[o][x]] = 1 

        return "empate" #si no se cumple nada es empate
    else: return columns # si hay ganador al contar por columnas se retorna el valor
```

**Probamos**

```py
ganador = get_winner(juego)
print(f'el jagador es "{ganador}"')
#salida -> el jagador es "O"
```

No estoy seguro que sea el mejor algoritmo, ni que sea el mas eficiente, pero por ahora esta bien