# Suma de pares igual a 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Hola tengo el siguiente código:

```
def marcar_par(T):
    rango=len(T)
    pila=[]
    for i in range(rango):
        for j in range(rango-1):
            if T[i][j]!=0:
                pila.append([T[i][j],i,j])
            else: 
                if pila!=[] and T[i][j+1]!=0:
                    tope=pila.pop()
                    if T[i][j+1]+tope[0]==10:
                        T[i][j+1]=0
                        T[tope[1]][tope[2]]=0
                        
    return T
```

Pero necesito que por ejemplo:

Elementos dentro de T2:[0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1][0, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4][5, 6, 2, 5, 0, 1][0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1][1, 0, 8, 3, 9, 4][8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]

En la listas si un número con el que le sigue sin importar que este o estos sean ceros, cambien por 0 también,

Así tendría que quedar:

Elementos dentro de T2:[0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1][0, 7, 7, 7, 2, 4][5, 6, 2, 5, 6, 1][0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1][1, 0, 8, 3, 9, 4][8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Explicación: Se debe reemplazar todos los pares de número que sumen 10, pero que se encuentren separados horizontalmente solamente por 0s, no se si así queda más claro

Si alguien me pudiera echar una mano sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: puedes leer esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440632/verificar-vecinos-en-un-array-bidimensional-python)

Comment: cuales son los datos de entrada y segun que se debe de colocar el 0?

Comment: Los datos de entrada son los que están indicado con la T y si es igual a 10 se tiene que colocar el 0

Comment: la pregunta que te di te ayudará bastante

Comment: existe alguna condición para que cambie a 0?

Comment: Que los vecinos sumen 10

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el código de tu pregunta, me lo podrías explicar un poco?

Comment: No se entiende nada en esta ensalada: "En la listas si un número con el que le sigue sin importar que este o estos sean 0s cambien por 0 también,"

Comment: Se debe reemplazar todos los pares de número que sumen 10, pero que se encuentren separados horizontalmente solamente por 0s, no se si así queda más claro

Comment: Ahi esta mejor. Ahora edita la pregunta y agrega esa explicación}

Comment: Gracias, si me pudieras ayudar sería de gran ayuda, de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si tienes `[8, 1, 9, 2]`?

Comment: @ChemaCortes debe retornar `[8,0,0,2]`

Comment: Alguno me podría ayudar?

Comment: @Hernan entra al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127524/discussion-between-hernan-and-christian)

Comment: @Christian ¿Y por qué no `[0, 0, 0, 0]`?¿Es aceptable `[8, 0, 0, 2]` como resultado?

Comment: @ChemaCortes si es aceptable, por que los ceros son el resultado de una modificación a la lista

Answer (score 1):

Solución:

```
def procesar(sublista):
    cadena = [(int(sublista[pos]), int(pos)) for pos in range(len(sublista)) if sublista[pos]]
    cadena.append((0,0))
    resultado = [0] * len(sublista)
    i = 0
    while cadena[i][0]:
        if cadena[i][0] + cadena[i+1][0] == 10:
            i += 1
        else:
            resultado[cadena[i][1]] = cadena[i][0]
        i += 1

    return resultado
```

La función recibe una lista de valores numéricos de largo arbitrario

```
[8, 1, 0, 9]
```

devolviendo otra lista transformada de acuerdo a las especificaciones.

Lo primero es preparar el resultado inicializando todo a cero:

```
resultado = [0] * len(sublista)
```

Con la sublista se genera una lista de tuplas con el valor e indice de cada elemento no cero:

```
cadena => [(8, 0), (1, 1), (9, 3)]
```

Por comodidad, agregamos un valor centinela al final, para no tener que estar revisando limites antes de acceder a los elementos:

```
cadena => [(8, 0), (1, 1), (9, 3), (0, 0)]
```

Si recorremos esta cadena podemos acceder a los elementos consecutivos no cero, calcular y comprobar su suma:

```
if cadena[i][0] + cadena[i+1][0] == 10:
```

Si la suma da, los dos valores deben ser descartados. No tengo que hacer nada aparte de avanzar el indice en dos posiciones, pues los ceros ya están puestos en la salida.

Si la suma no da, proceso a copiar el elemento al resultado.

#### Demo

```
T= [[2,0,0,3], [0, 0, 0, 9], [ 8, 1, 0, 9], [ 3, 0, 0, 7]]

def procesar(sublista):
    cadena = [(int(sublista[pos]), int(pos)) for pos in range(len(sublista)) if sublista[pos]]
    print(cadena)
    cadena.append((0,0))
    resultado = [0] * len(sublista)
    i = 0
    while cadena[i][0]:
        if cadena[i][0] + cadena[i+1][0] == 10:
            i += 1
        else:
            resultado[cadena[i][1]] = cadena[i][0]
        i += 1

    return resultado


for sublista in T:
    print(sublista, end=" ")
    print(procesar(sublista))
```

produce:

```
[2, 0, 0, 3] [2, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 9] [0, 0, 0, 9]
[8, 1, 0, 9] [8, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 0, 0, 7] [0, 0, 0, 0]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hola, use la función pero me sale: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Tienes que pasarle una sublista, no `T` completo. Llamala dentro de un `for sublista in T: procesar(sublista)`

Comment: Como?, en que parte debería estar eso?

Comment: Estudia las tres últimas líneas (`for sublista in T:`) de la demo en mi respuesta.

Comment: Ok, pero procesar no estaría definido o si?

Comment: Creo que mejor publicas una nueva pregunta con el código que estás ejecutando, porque no visualizo qué haces.

Comment: Es que me gustaría seguir trabajando sobre el código que ya tenía, no se si pudieses revisar o algo, porque solo me falla en 7 preguntas, por si me puedes ayudar, es el mismo que está en la pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127541/discussion-between-hernan-and-candid-moe).

Comment: Este es un sitio de preguntas-respuesta. Haces una pregunta, obtienes una respuesta. Trabajas en tu código. Si te topas con otra dificultad, haces otra pregunta. No te puedo ayudar porque no veo que haces.

Answer (score 0):

Holaa, espero sea lo que buscas deje un comentario donde puedo estar equivocandome!

```
t = [[2,0,0,3], [0, 0, 0, 9], [ 8, 1, 0, 9], [ 3, 0, 0, 7]]
def marcar_par(array):
    nuevoArray = []
    for numeros in array:
        #Para este punto si se utilizo t como parametro numeros en la primera iteracion seria "[2,0,0,3]"
        if numeros[0] + numeros[1] == 10:#si el primero con el segundo.
            nuevoArray.append([0,0,0,0]) ##pusheamos al nuevo array el resultado de esta revision , lo mismo en cada condicion encadenada del if
        elif numeros[0] + numeros[2] == 10:#el primero con el tercero
            nuevoArray.append([0,0,0,0])
        elif numeros[0] + numeros[3] == 10: #el primero con el cuarto
            nuevoArray.append([0,0,0,0])
        elif numeros[1] + numeros[2] == 10:#el segundo con el tercero
            nuevoArray.append([numeros[0],0,0,numeros[3]]) #aca devolvera tambien el ultimo como estaba en caso de que deba ser cero solo reemplazar
        elif numeros[1] + numeros[3] == 10: #el segundo con el cuarto
            nuevoArray.append([numeros[0],0,0,0])
        elif numeros[2] + numeros[3] == 10: #el tercero con el cuarto
            nuevoArray.append([numeros[0],numeros[1],0,0])
    return nuevoArray #devolvemos el array procesado


print(marcar_par(t))
```

Comment: y si el tamaño de la matriz cambia?

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido correctamente, lo que quieres es que cuando la suma de los números pares sea diez, a partir de ahí el resto de números de las listas sea cambiado por cero.

Tu estructura para resolverlo es buena, lo único que después utilizas los indices, cuando puedes hacerlo más sencillo. Se puede resolver de muchas formas, una solución sería esta:

```
lista_prueba = [[2,0,0,3], [0, 0, 0, 9], [ 8, 1, 0, 9], [ 3, 0, 0, 7]]

def marcar_par(listas):

    sum_total = 0                                           # Esta variable contará cuando llegemos a 10
    lista_resultado = []                                    # Esta es la lista que retornaremos

    for idx, lista in enumerate(listas):                    # Iteramos por cada sublista Enumerate nos devuelve la posición y la lista con la que estamos operando
        lista_resultado.append([])                          # Tenemos que crear nuestra sublista en lista_resultado
        for numero in lista:                                # Iteramos por los números de cada sublista
            if numero%2 == 0 and sum_total < 10:            # Si es par y sum_total aun no es 10 
                sum_total += numero                         # Sumamos dicho número a sum_total
                lista_resultado[idx].append(numero)         # y lo agregamos a la sublista de lista_resultado correspondiente
            elif sum_total >=10:                            # Si la suma total es mayor que 10, entonces empezamos a agregar ceros
                lista_resultado[idx].append(0)
            else:                                           # Si no cumple las anteriores condiciones simplemente agregamos el número
                lista_resultado[idx].append(numero)

    return lista_resultado

marcar_par(lista_prueba)
```

**Salida:** `[[2, 0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 0, 9], [8, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`

Una vez explicado el código la mayor duda que podrías tener es para que sirve `enumerate`. Esta función lo que hace es simplemente retornar la posición en el indice del item que se está iterando, y el propio item. Se utiliza sobre todo para evitar usar `range(len())`. Puedes saber más sobre esta función en la [documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Noo, lo que quiero es que si cuando la suma de un número que está al lado del otro sea 10 solo estos 2 cambien por 0 no todos los de la lista, en donde no importa si los números que están entre los otros 2 sean 0s, no se si me entiendes ahora